# Use TextureView programmatically with ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, surfaceview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, textureview

I create a `PlayerView` programmatically:

```
PlayerView playerView = new PlayerView(context);
```

Instead of using `SurfaceView`, I want it to use `TextureView`. In the documentation, it says to do the following:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
     android:id="@+id/player_view"
     app:surface_type="texture_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

However, like I said, I'm creating it programmatically, so how would I set it to use `TextureView` in my situation?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? need to use TextureView when using StyledPlayerView in Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create an XML file:

```
<com.xxx.xxx.PlayerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:surface_type="texture_view"
/>
```

Step 2: Create an AttributeSet

```
val xmlAttributes = context.resources.getXml(R.xml.player_view).let {
    try {
        it.next()
        it.nextTag()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // do something, log, whatever
    }
    Xml.asAttributeSet(it)
}
```

Step 3: Pass that into the constructor

```
PlayerView(context, xmlAttributes)
```

I'd like to note that this is stupid, you shouldn't have to do this, I hate that I had to, and I hate Exoplayer sometimes... (most times)

Comment: what is player_view here?